# How to programmatically log out a user in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I need to log a user out and redirect to a URL.

How would I do that in Drupal 7?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should call [`user_logout()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.pages.inc/function/user_logout/7).

Comment: +1 and then [`drupal_goto()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7)

Comment: user_logout() in D6 and D7 finish with their own drupal_goto(). I'm not convinced that your own call after that point would be processed.

Comment: Not clear how this answers 2nd part of Q: how to redirect to a URL after logging out, since in D7 `drupal_goto()` calls `user_logout()` anyway.

Answer (score 6):

use this any where

```
 <?php
module_load_include('pages.inc', 'user');
user_logout();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using the Rules module.  You can set a rule up to redirect to a URL after a user logs out and various other rules if needed.

http://drupal.org/project/rules